# why perl testing dir -d " " on windows returns true? bug or not?

Tags: windows, perl

Is there any explanation for perl returning true when testing a space-string dir on Windows?
Run on Windows7:

```
  perl -e "print qq{found\n} if -d qq{ }"
```

You will get output: `found`

But same perl code returns false on Linux.

Tested on perl 5.8 and strawberry perl 5.18 on Windows

Is it a bug or have an unconventional reasoning?

Comment: what does `perl -wle"print for stat(' ')"` show?

Comment: @ysth, `16832` (`040700`) for the third field (`$mode`), `0` for everything else.

Comment: Can't create a file with that name ("No such file or directory").

Comment: I consider this a bug. I don't think this is new. I seem to remember running into this years ago.

Comment: It has been a common practice to use "if -d $dirname" to test a directory exists or not.  But should not for Windows, unless this bug is fixed or add an additional test to guard against space strings.  Why this bug has not been fixed for a such long time?

Answer (score 0):

Under windows, any perl operation that internally tries to test a file or directory for existence uses the Win32 function `CreateFile`. Under windows a filename ending in spaces is not legal (although not clearly documented), and for some strange reason the `CreateFile` function internally strips all trailing spaces before trying to open the file/directory.

Since a name starting with space looks like a relative path, the space is first appended to your current working directory but then internally ignored by the Win32 function. This results in the directory test seeing your current directory and reporting success.

The perl `stat` function then proceeds to acquiring additional information and seems to somewhere down the line handle the trailing space(s) differently and therefore fails to get any further information. However it seems to explicitly leave the *mode* attribute of the stat result set, because it earlier had deduced that there existed a directory.

So yes, I would call this a bug in the windows port of perl, but fixing it is probably not as easy as it sounds, as there are lots of special cases for UNC paths, reparse points, NTFS/FAT filesystems etc. that makes correct handling of trailing spaces rather tricky.

Your best bet would probably be to explicitly strip trailing spaces from any assumed directory name at a very early point (who needs that anyway) and croak if nothing is left after stripping.